# Javascript - Sort an array of strings that can contain letters,numbers and dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
  var array=['sss_aaa_2013-09-25_part1.txt',
 'sss_aaa_2013-09-25_part2.txt',
 'sss_aaa_2013-09-25_part3.txt',
 'sss_aaa_2013-09-25_part12.txt',
 'sss_aaa_2013-09-25_part4.txt',
 'sss_aaa_2013-09-26_part10.txt',
 'sss_aaa_2013-09-26_part1.txt'];
```

For that above array i need to sort like below.How can i do this.

```
var result=['sss_aaa_2013-09-25_part1.txt',
 'sss_aaa_2013-09-25_part2.txt',
 'sss_aaa_2013-09-25_part3.txt',
 'sss_aaa_2013-09-25_part4.txt',
 'sss_aaa_2013-09-25_part12.txt',
 'sss_aaa_2013-09-26_part1.txt',
 'sss_aaa_2013-09-26_part10.txt'];
```